# Application builded using Dynamic framework not submitted to app store

Tags: ios, sdk, frameworks

I have created Dynamic Framework , While importing this dynamic framework into Application it needs to be add in Embedded Binaries.

it is working with Both Device and Simulator but when i archive and make .IPA file to submit , I got Below error while submitting app to app store.

1) ERROR ITMS-90087: "Unsupported Architectures. The executable for sample.app/Frameworks/customFramework.framework contains unsupported architectures '[x86_64, i386]'."

2) ERROR ITMS-90209: "Invalid Segment Alignment. The app binary at 'sample.app/Frameworks/customFramework.framework/CustomFramework' does not have proper segment alignment. Try rebuilding the app with the latest Xcode version.”

3) ERROR ITMS-90125: "The binary is invalid. The encryption info in the LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO load command is either missing or invalid, or the binary is already encrypted. This binary does not seem to have been built with Apple's linker.”

4) WARNING ITMS-90080: "The executable 'Payload/sample.app/Frameworks/customFramework.framework' is not a Position Independent Executable. Please ensure that your build settings are configured to create PIE executables. For more information refer to Technical Q&A QA1788 - Building a Position Independent Executable in the iOS Developer Library."

Any insights into this would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal if you make fat dynamic framework, they don't let the simulator architecture to be submitted (but it work with static library), the easiest way to solve it is to borrow the solution from other framework, eg [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/), they provide a script to strip out the simulator architectures out of the framework, so that the app can be submitted to appstore, check out their installation for framework version to include and use the script for your framework